Sci-fi movie where crew travels to a planet and turn extremely violent
A crew is sent to an alien planet for some kind of mining operation, but when they get there the crew members start turning against each other in extremely violent ways.
It is discovered that the planet is actually an organic mass that is bringing out aggression in humans on purpose to study them. By the end of the film i think most of the crew is dead.
Colour, would've been relatively recent, 2000 onwards and in English
A mostly white crew, one or two females. The name Nathan seems to strike a bell but I cannot remember if that was the actor's name or the characters name.
Anyone know which movie it is?

Do you have any more information? What year did you watch it? In cinema or TV? Colour or b/w? Which language? Could it dubbed? Any details about the crew? How many ppl? All male? Appearance? ...  Anything could help to identify this film.

@Marzipanherz i watched in in 2015 i think, it was at home on TV, in colour, wouldve been relatively recent, 2000 onwards, it was in english, mostly white crew, one or two females. The name Nathan seems to strike a bell but i cannot remember if that was the actor's name or the characters name

It's called infini. Here is the plot from wiki:

In the early 23rd century, an emergency is declared on a mining
  station O.I. Infini, and a search and rescue (SAR) team is sent in
  using Slipstream, a form of teleportation that allows near
  instantaneous travel. The location of O.I. Infini is proximal to a
  number of black holes meaning the mission operatives will experience
  severe time dilation.

